# Can I distribute a GPL executable (not a library) in a closed-source application?

Tags: licensing, gpl, linking

I want to write a closed-source desktop application that uses a piece of GPL software in the background.

I know that I can't link to a GPL library (`libgit.a`).  But if I embed a GPL application (`git.exe`) into a closed source application, unzip the GPL app to a temporary location, and then make calls to it using some form of IPC (e.g. command line arguments), is that legal?

- non-GPL application calls a GPL application at the command line -> definitely legal
- non-GPL application links to a GPL application using function calls -> definitely illegal
- non-GPL application bundles, distributes, and calls a GPL application at the command line -> ?

Distributing a GPL application and making silent IPC calls is functionally identical to linking, as far as the end-user is concerned.  Does GPL care about whether I'm linking inside of one process, or using IPC to do the linking?  It seems like closed source applications like GitHub's desktop clients do this, but maybe I'm misunderstanding how they work.

NOTE: This is different than the other GPL questions on this site, because it asks about embedding a GPL *application*, not linking to a library in the traditional sense.  The answers have been specific to this case and very helpful to me.

NOTE2: Mods found a new duplicate, and this time they are right - it is actually asking the same question as this (although the details are a little more jumbled).  The best [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/289924/108337) has been modded into oblivion though.  Key points are copied here:

- VMWare Server's example shows that it's okay to include the object code into your distribution and

  - install it alongside your program
  - pack it into a compound file within its footage if it's clearly a compound file and can be taken apart with widely available tools (an ISO image)

Comment: As soon as you *embed* the GPL application into your code, it becomes a derivative work of theirs, and you fall foul of copyright law.  It doesn't matter how you subsequently use the executable.

Comment: By the way, this question would probably fit nicely into the new [Beta OpenSource.SE](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/), in fact, I wouldn't be surprised to learn that it has already been asked and answered there.

Comment: Even better: it turns out, it *hasn't* been asked there!

Comment: @gnat yes, I also linked that post in my answer but answers there are (IMO) based too much on _personal opinion_ (and I said I strongly disagree with them for reasons I tried to explain).

Comment: "Can I use GPL, LGPL, MPL..." asks about using a library.  I'm specifically asking about *not* using a library, but rather an application in an encapsulated way.  The answers have been helpful in addressing that particular nuance.

Comment: Thanks for the OpenSource reference @Jorg.  If this question were languishing I would definitely repost, but as it has gotten some useful answers, it seems spammy for me to double-post.

Comment: I was late to the party to post my answer and posted it as http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/289924/108337 instead. It covers the matter better than the accepted answer in the question this was marked as a duplicate of (specifically, it points to the root principle of the distinction), but it has too many details specific to this question to permanently reside there.
Can we reopen this question to move it here on these grounds?

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer ivan!  I appreciate all the answers, but providing the VMWare Server example is the most helpful of them.  It seems that my question really is a duplicate of the other one (although the other question is not as explicit about the "not-linking"), and it sucks that you got downvoted.

Comment: I got downvoted because that answer was not for that question! That question is much more general, it asks about GPL+LGPL+MPL(+other similar licenses implied), all versions, which all say different things! While I focused on GPLv2 specifically! It's impossible to address them all at once in this level of detail, complete with references!

Comment: Looks like the 1st-tier people don't readily see this difference, and the question isn't gonna be reopened the easy way. Guess I should bring this up on Meta - if the scope of that question is appropriate and comparable to this one.

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer**: you're not forced to release your software under GPL; you can do it because you're making interoperability with GPL software and this doesn't make your software a derivative work (but if you want to feel more *safe* then don't distribute Git *inside* your application package, a dependency is OK).

**Dirty workaround** to avoid licensing headaches: note that if you make your package independent from Git and you have a separated *Source Control Integration Layer* then you may *want* to release under GPL (with source code on GitHub?!) only your Git integration module (not whole software which, in theory, is abstracted and compatible with any SCM).

Note that this question has been asked before: [Can I use GPL software in a commercial application?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47032/can-i-use-gpl-software-in-a-commercial-application) but I completely disagree with given accepted answer and I'll try to explain why. GPL needs to **overprotect** itself to avoid abuses and misuses but its bounds are set by law and it can't prevaricate them.

**Long answer**: it's a common debate about GPL, you'll find both point of views (it's derivative work or it's not). I'm not a lawyer (and this *issue* has been disccused in a court too few times to have a well-known universally accepted answer) but let's try to summarize.

GPL ties you to distribute your source code if you deploy any derivative work based on GPL. First of all check if Git has a [GPL linking exception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPL_linking_exception) (in that case you can freely use it). Main point is then to define *derivative work*. What they say about this (quotation from FAQ)?

> If the program dynamically links plug-ins, and they make function calls to each other and share data structures, we believe they form a single program, which must be treated as an extension of both the main program and the plug-ins. This means the plug-ins must be released under the GPL or a GPL-compatible free software license, and that the terms of the GPL must be followed when those plug-ins are distributed.

For US law *derivative work* is:

> “derivative work” is a work based upon one or more pre-existing works, such as a translation, musical arrangement, dramatization, fictionalization, motion picture version, sound recording, art reproduction, abridgment, condensation, or any other form in which a work may be recast, transformed, or adapted.

How you define *transformed* and *adapted* from copyright point of view (in US law)?

> This previously published material makes the work a derivative work under the copyright law. To be copyrightable, a derivative work must be different enough from the original to be regarded as a “new work” or must contain a substantial amount of new material. Making minor changes or additions of little substance to a preexisting work will not qualify the work as a new version for copyright purposes.

You have to incorporate GPL material in your own application. **To use it is not enough** to define your work as *derivative*. If you think about it then this is pretty obvious (and important!) because if you *use* Git to manage your source code you don't need to release your application under GPL!

Moreover they also says that:

> Titles, short phrases, and format, for example, are not copyrightable

Then now you also know that you have to include *enough* GPL material in your own work. A code snippet copied & pasted in your own code doesn't make it tied to GPL.

It seems that US law and GPL agree about *derivative work* but note that GPL is much more specific: they explicitly say **they make functions calls [...] and share data structures**. If you include `git.exe` in your program then you're not making any function call. It's (in theory) perfectly allowed by GPL license.

In fact they later explicitly says that:

> If the program dynamically links plug-ins, but the communication between them is limited to invoking the ‘main’ function of the plug-in with some options and waiting for it to return, that is a borderline case.

Also note that they generically speak about *plugin* so it may be applied also to dynamic linked libraries where you invoke just one function (although IMO it should also be *the only* exported function).

Dependent code is not derivative code, interoperability doesn't make your code a derivative work. There is even sentence from an US court for a similar issue: [Lewis Galoob Toys, Inc. v. Nintendo of America, Inc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_Galoob_Toys,_Inc._v._Nintendo_of_America,_Inc.).

Note that they also say:

> If the program uses fork and exec to invoke plug-ins, then the plug-ins are separate programs, so the license for the main program makes no requirements for them.

There is no mention about deployment method (one single package or a dependency).

**According to GPL license you're in doubt but according to US law you have to *incorporate* GPL material to be tied to GPL license**. You can do it without any problem but if you want to feel more *safe* then make it a *dependency* (installed together with your package or a mandatory prerequisite),

Given all these hard reasoning then:

> non-GPL application calls a GPL application at the command line -> definitely legal

Yes, if *connection* between your code and Git takes place at user's computer then you're not restricted by GPL in any way.

> non-GPL application links to a GPL application using function calls -> definitely illegal

Maybe not. If you invoke just one *main* plugin function then it may be a borderline case which IMO should be avoided because contrary to GPL spirit. If you don't like just don't use it.

> non-GPL application bundles, distributes, and calls a GPL application at the command line -> ?

Legal, dependent code is not derivative code and interoperability doesn't make your code a derivative work. Moreover they explicitly states that if you use `fork`/`exec` then it's not derivative or combined work (no mention about deployment).

From Scott's link a [lawyer](http://www.epiclaw.net/2012/01/31/combining-or-linking-proprietary-software-unmodified-code-licensed-under-gplv2) explains this issue with much deeper knowledge and better wording, I'd like to highlight one passage from that article (emphasis is mine):

> The phrase, "This General Public License does not permit incorporating your program into proprietary programs", comes after the "END OF TERMS AND CONDITIONS" statement.  It is not part of the license itself.  In any case, the statement is not supported by the text of the license.  The GPL does not prohibit incorporating proprietary programs; **at best**, it requires that proprietary programs be subject to the GPL's inheritance obligations.

Also re-read *dirty workaround* I suggested at beginning if you want to feel *safe*.

Comment: This answer has the potential to be dangerously inaccurate.  As far as I'm aware, what the OP wants to do would normally be done by saying "here's my software, it needs git, but I can't bundle it with my software, so go download and install it yourself."  Even then I'm not 100% sure, and I'm pretty sure it's hard to prove what you're saying too.  I'm pretty sure this'll get closed because it requires legal advice.

Comment: @No, they (who wrote GPL license) explicitly _handle_ this cases.It's not _such_ inaccurate at least because it's not based on personal opinion.

Comment: Here is an interesting discussion of this issue [written by a lawyer](http://www.epiclaw.net/2012/01/31/combining-or-linking-proprietary-software-unmodified-code-licensed-under-gplv2) (apparently).

Comment: @ScottWhitlock yes, it's a reasonable (!) position of course (but IMO too few cases to have a solid background). However we're discussing about _deployment_. If you call an executable then your application is not _derivative work_ nor _combined work_. Even for GPL itself if you simply _invoke a function_ you're in a bordercase.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: "If you call an executable then your application is not derivative work nor combined work" Then it is *not neccessarily* a derivative work. Look on the FSF site, or read the license, for the details.

Comment: @Deduplicator sorry, I didn't understand what you mean...

Comment: Why the h*** has nobody ever funded a lawyer to answer such questions. The FSF and other organizations spend millions to check code for vulnerabilities etc. but leave us in doubt about such important questions.

Comment: @Thomas because it's somehow a gray area. After all FSF is trying to _sell_ this license as a _contract_ (which legally...can't be) and jurisdiction matters. Think that free software MUST live together with non-free then there must be some freedom, unfortunately sometimes this freedom is misinterpreted or abused (in both ways).

Comment: GNU FAQ #GPLPlugins also mention: shared memory to communicate with complex data structures is pretty much equivalent to dynamic linking. I am guessing the safer way is to write shared memory code on proprietary code and GPL code. If the market value is good, it should worth the effort. So you can contribute certain percent of profit back to community.

Answer (score 2):

The answer [by Andriano Repetti](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/49723/adriano-repetti) is perhaps correct but you should **ask a lawyer** (and I am not a lawyer neither), or perhaps the FSF or the copyright owners of the `git`software.

Be aware that some people think (and I believe that) if you adapt some GPL software (even if you publish your adapted source code under GPL!) to communicate with your own proprietary product by using a specific, *ad-hoc*, protocol (e.g. your JSONRPC on pipes) it is not legal (AFAIU) since your code is in that case a derivative work. Things are often different if the same protocol is used by several applications, including a free software one.

<sup>The point is that *linking* or *derivative work*  has a different meaning to lawyers and judges that for developers. In some countries, the intent you have also matters!</sup>

But *I am not a lawyer*, and you really should ask one. You could also as a courtesy ask the authors of the free software, or even ask the FSF (or the FSFE in Europe, or APRIL or AFUL in France).

BTW, embedding in a compressed file the executable of `git` inside your application is certainly against the spirit of GPL, since your user is not able to *easily* replace your `git` by his own updated or improved version of `git`. However, you could package `git.exe` (probably with the source tar ball of that `git`) and tell your user that he/she needs to install it (and where, and how). If he wanted to upgrade `git` he should be able to do that easily (so please tell him how to do that). Even if such an executable embedding is legal (and I wish it is not), doing that is certainly user unfriendly. If using `git` you should at least explain your users which version ranges of `git` you want, and how to upgrade the `git` binary.

(Explanations around GCC plugins such as [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) 
and GCC runtime license exception and discussions around it might be relevant)

You might consider publishing your software with a free software license. It might be wiser and costs less to you. And you could then get external contributions and feedback.

Comment: I agree with _"ask a layer"_ (absolutely!) but can you please explain better why you think if you make a _communication_ plugin (released under GPL) you also should release under GPL the _target_ application? They're separate works, I'm interested in that position!

Comment: Because it is considered as derivative work and/or linking. IIRC, there have been some lawsuite somewhere in Europe about that. This is why you should ask a lawyer. And Sun did that in the past on GCC, and that was part of the motivation for the FSF to go from GPLv2 to GPLv3. See also the GCC runtime exception

Comment: If there is a modification on the original GPLed code to actively support this _bridge_ then I'd tend to agree too but if it's a merely an _interface_ then GPL can't apply (IMO). GPL _may_ be inherited but it's not transitive (friends of friends...)

Comment: I don't know laws, and I am a free software enthusiast and contributor to GCC. So I am very biased. Also, I live in France and know nothing about US laws.

Comment: Let's imagine you have a bank application. You can produce reports in a format (and using its libraries) of a GPL licensed software. Should you release your software also with GPL? Well I live in Italy (but our law isn't much different in this case) and yes I'm free software enthusiast too but I don't want to see it _viral_ (I fear it's more counterproductive, think linux kernel notes...)

Comment: It depends if I am using a well known and documented format, or if I had to patch the GPL software to suite the needs of that bank application. But you really should ask the FSF (or some other free software organization: FSFE in Europe, or APRIL or AFUL in France). I am not the right person to discuss that. AFAIK this is one of the motivations of the GPLv2 -> GPLv3 transition (in addition of TIVOization)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: If you use one function (or possible even a few lines) from the GPL application in your bank application, then you must release the bank application as GPL. If you can create the file format of the GPL application without using GPL code, then you are free to choose the license of your bank application.

Comment: @bart amount matters because (unless is copyrighted algorithm itself) if you *copy* two lines of code then you are copying knowledge not *material*. It has been understood and accepted by law, whatever they write they can't go against what law says. If you, say, copy 3 lines for very efficient integer swapping from Linux kernel code then...?

Comment: Also note that it's not about opinion. I write a plug in to integrate my own IDE with git. I may (debatable) release such plug-in with GPL. Absolutely no obligation to release my IDE with GPL. Obviously otherwise no integration will be ever possible. Also note that GPL software reserve itself the right to link to non GPL code.

Comment: This is about what is **legal** (and it's legal much more than what OP is asking for). If you are talking about what is **spirit** then I can only agree with you. However they are different things. About quantity also think about license you release snippets on SE sites. What are the implications of its licenses on commercial software?

Comment: Moreover linking is a vague concept. Does it apply to remote services? Does location breaks license? No, of course. Can Microsoft integrate visual Studio with git? Yes, they did...